# How to convert List<Entity> to List<DTO> Objects using object mapper?

Tags: java, objectmapper

I have a method like this:

```
public List<CustomerDTO> getAllCustomers() {
    Iterable<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findAll();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return (List<CustomerDTO>) mapper.convertValue(customer, CustomerDTO.class);
}
```

when i try to convert `List` values i am getting below message

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.finman.customer.CustomerDTO out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: As a general rule, when you find yourself casting, you are probably not doing what you think you are doing (or want to be doing).

Comment: Why would you do that? Do you realize that this consists in serializing the customer to JSON, then parsing the JSON to a CustomerDTO? It's very inefficient, obscure, will fail at runtime if the two classes don't have the same structure, and won't support refactoring. Why don't you just create a constructor or a method creating a CustomerDTO from a Customer?

Answer (score 1):

```
mapper.convertValue(customer, CustomerDTO.class)
```

This attempts to create a single `CustomerDTO`, not a list of them.

Perhaps this will help:

```
mapper.readValues(customer, CustomerDTO.class).readAll()
```

Comment: What to use there then? and If i not use that CustomerDTO how object mapper will know which object to convert?

Comment: sorry missed that. i tried the same but got below warning
The method readValues(JsonParser, ResolvedType) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (Iterable<Customer>, Class<CustomerDTO>)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```java
static <T> List<T> typeCastList(final Iterable<?> fromList,
                                final Class<T> instanceClass) {
    final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    for (final Object item : fromList) {
        final T entry = item instanceof List<?> ? instanceClass.cast(item) : mapper.convertValue(item, instanceClass);
        list.add(entry);
    }

    return list;
}

// And the usage is
final List<DTO> castedList = typeCastList(entityList, DTO.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Customer> customerList = customerRepository.findAll();
    return customerList.stream().map(o -> mapper.convertValue(o, CustomerDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```